# mysql gem 2.7: impossible to install

Tags: mysql, rubygems

I'm trying to install the mysql gem v. 2.7 on MacOsX Snow Leopard.
I know a lot has been written about this, and I've read most of it.

If I do the following:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -v '2.7' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
can't dup NilClass
```

Instead, trying to install v 2.8 works fine:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...
```

But then I get this error when trying to start my local server:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.6 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000    
/Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes (NameError)
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:9:in `define_all_hashes_method!'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:68:in `mysql_connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/plugins/admin_data/lib/admin_data/settings.rb:65:in `initialize_defaults'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/plugins/admin_data/init.rb:36:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/config/environment.rb:9
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /Users/phishman/Sites/BlindDog/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.6/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from script/server:3:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

Can you help me?  Please, I've been breaking my head on this for 2 days :(
MySQL I'm using is the dmg downloaded from mysql.com.  I even tried to uninstall it and install mysql from macports but getting lots of errors, so I had to re-install from mysql.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to install mysql gem and make it work:

I installed rvm, istalled ruby 1.8.7 and made it the defualt ruby (instead of the system one), then I compiled and reinstalled all the gems using

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself. Googling turned up not only this question (which didn't help me - this project isn't ready for Bundler, plus we're using RVM so `sudo` is out) but also [IRC logs](http://irclogger.com/.rvm/2011-05-06) from when I asked the same question on the RVM IRC channel a year ago. (Hmm, this sounds familiar.)

If you don't feel like sifting through the IRC log, here's the summary: newer versions of Rubygems (e.g. 1.6.x, which RVM installs by default with ree-1.8.7, which is what we were using) don't play well with the mysql gem. Try this:

```
ree-1.8.7 $ rvm rubygems 1.5.2
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.5.2 for ree-1.8.7-2012.02 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ree-1.8.7 $ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -v 2.7 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.7...
ree-1.8.7 $
```

Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to this problem myself; we have an app that's running on an older version of ruby and rails.

I am using:

- rbenv
- Mac OS - Mavericks
- bundler
- ruby ree-1.8.7-2010.02

I had to downgrade rubygems:

```
gem update --system 1.5.2
```

Then I could install mysql 2.7 (and everything else) with:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install
```